# How to validate list of input tag using bootstrap validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, twitter-bootstrap, validation

How to validate list of input tag using bootstrap validator
I am using spring, jquery and bootstrap

Here is my html :

```
<form id="myForm" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="/hello">

<input class="form-control" type="text" name="myobject[0].descripton />
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="myobject[1].descripton />
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="myobject[2].descripton />
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="myobject[3].descripton />

</form>
```

Here is my validator :

```
$('#myForm').bootstrapValidator({
  feedbackIcons : { 
    valid : glyphicon glyphicon-ok,
    invalid : glyphicon glyhicon-remove
    validating : glyphicon glyphicon-refresh 
  },

  fields : {
    myobject[].description : {                 // <---name of tag.
      validators : {
        notEmpty : {
          message : 'this is required'
        }
       }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

In rails,bootstrap validator plugin first Download the bootstrap-toggle-master file and copy and past validator.js or validator.min.js file in your project.

And add the following code in your view

```
{<%= form_tag({controller: "facebook", action: "post_message", method: "post"}, :data => {:toggle => "validator"},:class => "facebook-post") do %>
          <div class="form-group">
           <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Please write something for your status and our wall</label>
            <%= text_area_tag :status_message, nil, class: "form-control", :rows => 3, :required => 'true', :data => {:error => "Please write something for both your status and our wall. E.g. Thanks very much for a great night."}%><div class="help-block with-errors"></div>

            <% if @venue_location.present? %>
                <small>- at </small><%= link_to @venue_location, @fb_page, target: '_blank' %>
            <% end %>
          </div>

          <% if ((@package == 'package3') && !(@fb_page.blank?)) %>
              <div class="facebook-like">
                <div class="fb-like"
                     data-href="<%= current_venue.facebook_page %>"
                     data-layout="standard"
                     data-action="like"
                     data-show-faces="false"
                     style="overflow: hidden">
                </div>
              </div>
          <% end %>

          <div class="btn-next text-right">
            <%= image_submit_tag("customer/icon-forward.png") %>
          </div>
    <% end %>}
```